# How to change the value of check box when it is checked or unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello guys here the problem. I want to perform a different calculation based on the check box.

```
<div>
 COD: <input type="checkbox" id="trigger" name="question" >
</div>
```

Here is the javascript for calculating the price of the item
the problem is that i dont know how can i do the else if method

```
<script>
    $("#price,#quant,#shipment").keyup(function () {
      if(+myFunction3() =="" )
      {
        $('#demo').val(0);
      }
      else if($('#trigger')=="checked") //this is the problem
      {
        $('#demo').val($('#price').val() * $('#quant').val() ;
      }
      else
      {
      $('#demo').val($('#price').val() * $('#quant').val() + +myFunction3());
     }
  });
  </script>
```

Advance thank you guys.

Comment: try:- `$('#trigger').is(":checked")`

Comment: Try this $('#trigger').is(':checked'), resource http://api.jquery.com/is/

Comment: If the above don't work, the verbose way to get the status is document.getElementById("trigger").checked

Comment: what's   +myFunction3  this?

Comment: @AtifTariq it will get the value of the shipping details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery you could do:

```
else if($('#trigger:checked').length > 0)
```

or

```
else if($('#trigger').is(':checked'))
```

If you want to re-run your calculation when a user checks or un-checks the checkbox, you could run the same code you run on the keyup function on:

```
$('#trigger').change(function() {
  ...
})
```

Comment: how can i make it like onkeyup ? because for example $('#demo').val($('#price').val() * $('#quant').val() + +myFunction3()); is calculated when I checked the value is not change automatically

Comment: @Jonas Dulay you want to run the calculation again when you check the box?

Comment: Yes yes yes .. Thats what i need

Comment: I dont know where to put it :(( Sorry .. Can we discuss it on chat?

Comment: Are "#price,#quant,#shipment" all inputs boxes? If so, you should be able to just change: "$("#price,#quant,#shipment").keyup(function () {" to $("#price,#quant,#shipment,#trigger").change(function () {" in the first line of your script tag.

Comment: Cant do it :( can you help me ? need help asap

Comment: OMG .. Thank you so much .. Im jumping in tears . !! I work on it in a day... I have my 4 projects more to do right now! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your script should be like this:

```
<script>
    $("#price, #quant, #shipment").keyup(function () {
      if(+myFunction3() =="" )
      {
        $('#demo').val(0);
      }
      else if ($('#trigger').is(':checked')) { //this is the problem

        $('#demo').val($('#price').val() * $('#quant').val() ;
      }
      else
      {
      $('#demo').val($('#price').val() * $('#quant').val() + +myFunction3());
     }
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: how can i make it like onkeyup ? because for example $('#demo').val($('#price').val() * $('#quant').val() + +myFunction3()); is calculated when i checked the value is not change automatically

Comment: Theres is no changes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
    $("#price,#quant,#shipment").keyup(function () {
      if(+myFunction3() =="" )
      {
        $('#demo').val(0);
        return;
      }

      var isCOD = $('#trigger').is(':checked');
      var val = $('#price').val() * $('#quant').val();

      if (isCOD) 
      {
         val += myFunction3();
      }

      $('#demo').val(val);
     }
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this condition in else if:

```
else if($('input#trigger[type=checkbox]').is(":checked"))
```